# Как сделать чтобы уровень снежинки на каждом уровне уменьшался?

Tags: javascript

Снежинка Предположим, что снежинка образуется так: из центра вырастает 6 кристалликов - отрезков длины L, углы между соседними отрезками равны 60; из их "свободных" концов вырастает по 5 отрезков; соседние отрезки образуют углы по 60, длины этих отрезков в K раз меньше L; из их "свободных" концов аналогично вырастает по 5 новых отрезков, длина которых еще в К раз меньше, и так растет N "уровней" снежинки. Длина кристаллика на каждом уровне в K раз меньше длины кристаллика на предыдущем уровне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написать алгоритм, рисующий снежинку для любого уровня N.

Ссылка на код [https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/blackhawk13/yqkLpfzx/19/)

```js
k = 75; //{dlina lucha (iznachal'nogo)} 
n = 6; //{kolichestvo luchei} 
g = 2; //{glubina rekursii} 

function snezhinka(x, y, r, c) {
    if (c < 1) {
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        let arr = [];
        const alpha = 2 * Math.PI * i / n;
        xd = Math.round(x + r * Math.cos(alpha));
        yd = Math.round(y + r * Math.sin(alpha));
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(xd, yd);
        arr.push(xd, yd);
        console.log(arr);
        ctx.stroke();

        if (n > 1) {
            // n -= 1
            for (let j = 1; j < g; j++) {
                snezhinka(xd, yd, r / g, c - 1);
            }

        }
    }
}

snezhinka(250, 200, k, g);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не стоит вандализировать вопрос, даже если он вам не нравится

Answer (score 2):

```
function snezhinka(Total, N, X) {
    const L = 6;
    let arr = [];
    let temp;

    //let Kk = (N > 1) ? K : K / N;
    let Kk = K / (Total - N + 1);
    console.log(N, Kk);
    // Рисуем звезду
    for (let i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        const alpha = 2 * Math.PI * i / L;
        //console.log(Kk);
        xd = Math.round(X + Kk * Math.cos(alpha));
        yd = Math.round(Y + Kk * Math.sin(alpha));
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(X, Y);
        ctx.lineTo(xd, yd);
        arr.push([xd, yd]);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    if (N > 1) {
        temp = arr;
            snezhinka(Total, N - 1, temp[0][0]);
    }
}

snezhinka(3, 3, 250);
```